# a (pseudo)adjunction for the functor sending a category C to PSh(C) the category of presheaves

Tags: ct.category-theory

I've read about free cocompletion of categories discussing on the adjunction between Cat and cocompleteCat (Cat: category of small categories, cocompleteCat: category of small cocomplete categories and cocontinuous functors) where the adjunction is about a free cocompletion functor F which sends each category C to PSh(C), the category of its presheaves.
(http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cocompletion)

I wonder if the functor F have a left adjoint (even with some restrictions on its domain) and how it could be described.

Comment: Your description of the target is incorrect. Categories of presheaves are almost never small, and in fact Freyd showed that a small cocomplete category is a preorder. There are genuine set-theoretic difficulties here; e.g. because of the point I just mentioned it's not at all obvious what the forgetful functor is supposed to be.

Comment: This does not answer your question in any way. Just want to direct interested readers to the note [Sheaves and Homotopy Theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/cech.pdf) by Daniel Dugger, where the cocompletion business is explained in very accessible terms with lots of intuition. Specifically, $F$ and its *right* adjoint, the forgetful functor from cocomplete categories to arbitrary categories, are discussed. The size issues which Qiaochu refers to are ignored though.

Comment: @Ingo: the size issues are genuine here and ignoring them makes it easy to say things that are false. If $C$ is not (essentially) small, it is not true, as Dugger appears to be claiming, that presheaves on $C$ is the free cocompletion of $C$ (provided we agree that colimits, by default, should be over small diagrams; if we don't, then it is not true that presheaves form a cocomplete category. Freyd's argument above also shows that a category which admits all large colimits is a preorder).

Comment: Dugger's proof is incorrect because he never specifies whether colimits are supposed to be over small diagrams or over all diagrams, so he gets to say both "presheaves form a cocomplete category" (true over small diagrams) and "every presheaf is a colimit of representables" (true over large diagrams). The proof is correct if $C$ is (essentially) small; it establishes a universal property but does not describe an adjunction.

Comment: The forgetful 2-functor from *large* categories with small colimits to large categories has a genuine left adjoint which sends a small category C to PSh(C). But this left adjoint is not a right adjoint: PSh(*) is not final, since it has many colimit-preserving endofunctors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The free cocompletion functor $C \mapsto \widehat{C}$ (which, as Zhen Lin says, does not agree with the presheaf functor when $C$ is not essentially small) should in no reasonable sense have a left adjoint, since it is very far from preserving limits.

It already fails to preserve products: if $C, D$ are two small categories, then $\widehat{C \times D}$ is the "cocomplete tensor product" of $\widehat{C}$ and $\widehat{D}$, which is neither the product nor the coproduct in cocomplete categories. (This is closely analogous to the way in which the free abelian group functor sends a product to a tensor product, which is neither the product nor the coproduct in abelian groups.) In fact the product of $\widehat{C}$ and $\widehat{D}$ is $\widehat{C \sqcup D}$. So we already get a counterexample by taking $C$ and $D$ to be discrete categories with $3$ objects, say.

Comment: the counterexample is good. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the correct statement:

> Let $\mathfrak{Cat}$ be the 2-category of locally small categories (and all functors) and let $\mathfrak{Cocomp}$ be the 2-category of locally small cocomplete categories (and all cocontinuous functors). Then the forgetful functor $\mathfrak{Cocomp} \to \mathfrak{Cat}$ has a left biadjoint. More precisely, for every locally small category $\mathcal{C}$, there is a locally small cocomplete category $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ and a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \hat{\mathcal{C}}$ such that the induced functor
>   $$\mathfrak{Cocomp} (\hat{\mathcal{C}}, \mathcal{D}) \to \mathfrak{Cat} (\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D})$$
>   is an equivalence of categories for all locally small cocomplete $\mathcal{D}$.

In the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is essentially small, $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is equivalent to $[\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$; in general, it is a certain full subcategory.

(Note that we may take "locally small" in the weak sense of "hom-sets are small sets", without any condition on the set of objects.)

Answer (score 0):

> In the case where $C$ is essentially small, $\hat{C}$ is equivalent to $[C^\text{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$; in general, it is a certain full subcategory.

Let me make this statement precise, as it is actually the tricky part.

A presheaf $H\colon C^\text{op} \to Set$ is called *small* if $H = \mathrm{Lan}_JF$ for some full inclusion $J\colon D \hookrightarrow C^\text{op}$. Equivalently, a presheaf is a small colimit of representables (in a bigger universe). Roughly speaking, $H$ is determined by a small full subcategory of $C$.

Then, the category $\mathcal{P}C$ of small presheaves with natural transformations forms the free cocompletion of $C$ via the usual Yoneda embedding. This gives you the left biadjoint to the forgetful functor $U\colon \mathbf{ConCAT} \to \mathbf{CAT}$ where $\mathbf{ConCAT}$ is the 2-category of large categories with colimits as objects, cocontinuous functors as 1-cells, and natural transformations as 2-cells; $\mathbf{CAT}$ the 2-category of large categories. In addition, the forgetful functor is also (pseudo-)monadic. The pseudomonad can be a strict 2-monad if a choice of colimits is given.

Small functors were introduced as accessible functors in (Kelly, 1982), and the monadicity of cocompletion can be found in (Kelly & Lack, 2000).

- Kelly, Basic Concepts of Enriched Category Theory, 1982
- Kelly and Lack, On the monadicity of categories with chosen colimits, 2000